# Small embeddable web/HTTP stack for C#?

Tags: c#, .net, embeddedwebserver

This might be too much to ask. (Why on earth would I want to depart from IIS after all?)

What I'm looking for is a pretty good embeddable HTTP server.  I've looked around, and I'm not yet sold on [Kayak](https://github.com/kayak/kayak).  But I haven't found many others.

Can anyone recommend a reliable, embeddable HTTP Server written in C#?  Preferably one that implements the [Python WSGI](http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) spec, that would be awesome.

Comment: Might want to expand on "not yet sold on Kayak" - e.g. what is missing or desired? Also, what is the overall goal/purpose? Running an ASP.NET application? Hosting vanilla HTML? Old-school CGI (or WSGI)? A custom web-service with no "standard Microsoft" Web dependencies?

Comment: What do you mean, "for C#"? Do you mean "for .NET"? In which case, which version of .NET? Does it need to be _written_ in C# or would it be ok if it were written in another managed language?

Comment: @pst I'm looking for something that's a lot like the Jetty DropWizard implementation. See: http://dropwizard.codahale.com/getting-started/  I doubt there's anything that's really close to that implementation, but maybe starting with an HTTP server I can work on getting closer.

Comment: @John Sauders I prefer the C# language over the other Managed Languages, so ultimately I'd prefer the implementation be done in C#.  And you are right for .NET, and I'd want to run it on a .net 4.5 machine.  I've been thinking that maybe SignalR might have something I can use -- but haven't really research it deeply enough.

Comment: Why do you care what language it's written in, if it works?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Because I'd like to hack on it -- and I loath VB.

Comment: "not yet sold on Kayak" -- well, now with the benefit of time, as of today the last meaningful commit on the github repo was > 5 years ago...

Comment: For ASP.NET Core, Microsoft has released Kestrel: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?tabs=aspnetcore2x